# Absolute value constraint in quadratic programming optimization

Tags: convex-optimization, quadratic-programming, cvx, cvxpy

$$
argmin(x,y)=x^2+y^2+2y
$$

$$
s.t.\ \  y=|x-10|
$$

How can I convert the absolute value constraint to the constraint matrix (GX<=h, AX=b) in `cvxopt`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think that you can replace your equality constraint by two inequality constraints.

Comment: Are you aware of standard techniques for dealing with absolute values in the objective of what would otherwise be an LP?  Can you see why the $y^{2}$ term is easy to deal with?